# wireless speedtest slower than wired speedtest

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a 15 mbs internet connection from TimeWarner.  I have 4 devices connected to the router wirelessly.  2 toshiba laptops, a Samsung galaxy 10 and an LG Thrive smartphone.When I do a speed test to speedtest.net I get over 10mps down on the galaxy and the lg, both android systems.  The same test on the 2 toshibas results in a painfully slow. 1.2mps down on them.I have analyzed the signals and changed to a non bsy channel, I have turned off power management on the wifi adapter on the toshibas. On the Galaxy I have had the same fast results whether I use the speedtest app or go to the site using firefox. BTW if I connect the toshibas directly with a lan cable I also get good speed test results.  Any suggestions on how to speed up connection to my SMC8014 wireless router.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about which wireless protocols you are using

Comment: Could be your drivers, bad antennas, the spec you're using (wireless card), router prioritization, background processes in windows. Unfortunately, with the current info most answers will be guesses. You may want to research common reasons for this behavior and narrow in. My surface at one point was like that due to crappy drivers, regardless of my power settings it dwarfed the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop might be connected via 11b or 11g with lower datrates e.g. 54 mbps and througput e.g. 1-2 mbps, while your mobile is connected via 11n which has much higher datarates, e.g. 300 mbps and higher throuput.

You should be able to see the connected wifi data rate on your laptop.

Comment: While that's certainly possible, many consumer routers can only operate on the lowest connected device's spec. So if all were connected and the Toshiba was on b, they may all have to be on b. Again, not always the case but on a large portion of the routers that is true.